# What is the word for someone who ignores others and does what they want to

Tags: single-word-requests

This could be in a positive or negative way. So someone ignores people telling them to murder or someone ignores someone telling them to stop being rude. Basically how can you describe someone who just follows their gut in everything they do.

Comment: Are you looking for an adjective to describe such a person, or a noun which already carries this description?

Comment: I’ll probably be told that this is “better suited for Meta,” but I’ll ask it here anyway: **Under and by what reasoning and authority was my up-voted comment (along with others) deleted overnight?** To wit:
" [1 upvote]  Although perhaps not quite there yet (nor are the following single words), but such individuals often end up being [called]“loose cannons” or “lone wolves.” –  Papa Poule 17 hours ago"

Comment: @PapaPoule that is indeed a better question for Meta. There's a good discussion on it [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work). My favorite characterization from that link is that `comments are temporary 'Post-It' notes left on a question or answer`, which are always meant to be removed once their usefulness has expired. In a perfect stackexchange world, ALL comments would eventually be removed to leave a cleaner site for future readers. Your particular comment was probably removed because it was an answer, which is not what the comment functionality is for.

Comment: Well, I was going to post a [Cartman reference](http://i.imgur.com/6ZHW3sj.gif), but if it's just going to be deleted... Oh well, I think I'll ignore the site rules and do post it anyways because I want to. (And now I've left a different kind of meta comment.)

Comment: Honey badger. [He does what he wants!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4r7wHMg5Yjg)

Comment: Wouldn't assertive be an option in the positive side of that definition?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

obstinate

> **ob·sti·nate**
>   ˈäbstənət/
>   *adjective*
>   stubbornly refusing to change one's opinion or chosen course of action, despite attempts to persuade one to do so.

Taken from [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/obstinate).

Comment: Unyielding comes pretty close too.

Comment: +1..."The obstinate Man does not hold Opinions, but they hold him," wrote Samuel Butler way back in the seventeenth century

Comment: I knew I was missing the better option. I didn't realize obstinate applied to action, I thought it was just opinions. Then again thoughts become actions, so it makes sense! :)

Comment: Is it _really_ obstinacy to ignore people telling one to commit murder, as per the question?

Comment: I do not think this word is neutral enough. Obstinacy has negative connotations. One definition of the word is "(of an unwelcome phenomenon or situation) very difficult to change or overcome."

Answer (score 29):

What about "maverick"? That's the word that came to my mind, although the following formal definitions don't *exactly* match your description.

> [maverick](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/maverick):
>
> Adjective: Showing independence in thoughts or actions.
>
> Noun: One who does not abide by rules.

wiktionary.org

Comment: +1 That certainly captures well in one word (and with more neutrality)  the two suggestions that I made up in the comments.

Comment: This is what popped in my mind as well when I first read the question, though of course it carried with it some wonderful McCain/Palin imagery.

Comment: The source citation(s) for your link/block quote(s) should appear in plain text, rather than as a hypertext link (to avoid the disabling effects of link-rot), but +1 for "maverick."

Comment: Okay, but why haven't you told this to the other answers that do this?

Answer (score 11):

My choice(s) -

ONE WORD

> **[uncompromising](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/uncompromising)**  (adj)
>
> - not making concessions

TWO WORDS

> - **stubbornly obstructive** (unwilling to cooperate)

([vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/uncompromising))

Answer (score 6):

Someone who just sticks to their own opinions while ignoring those of others is:

**[self-opinionated](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/self-opinionated)** <sub>(Oxford)</sub>

> Having an arrogantly high regard for oneself or one’s own opinions:
>
> a pompous, self-opinionated bully

---

Not a single word, but try:

**[be your own person/woman/man](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/be-your-own-person-woman-man)** <sub>(Cambridge)</sub>

> to be in control of your life and not allow other people to tell you what to do:
>
> *Nobody tells me how to live my life - I'm my own man.*

Comment: IMO, self-opinionated answers it to the OPs sastisfaction.

Answer (score 6):

This sort of independent thinking (good or bad) is shown by someone who is **strong-minded**.

> **strong-minded**:  adjective   (**[Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/strong-minded)**)
>
> ```
> having strength of mind; firm, resolute, and determined
> ```

Comment: In a similar vein, the first word that popped into my mind was ***headstrong***.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet "Headstrong" is better than most of the actual answers here.

Answer (score 5):

**[Stubborn](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/stubborn?s=t)**

> **adjective**
>
> 1. unreasonably obstinate; obstinately unmoving:
>
>    - E.g. *a stubborn child.*
> 2. fixed or set in purpose or opinion; resolute:
>
>    - E.g. *a stubborn opponent of foreign aid.*
> 3. obstinately maintained, as a course of action:
>
>    - E.g. *a stubborn resistance.*
> 4. difficult to manage or suppress:
>
>    - E.g. *a stubborn horse; a stubborn pain.*

**[Indifferent](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/indifferent?s=t)**

> **adjective**
>
> 1. without interest or concern; not caring; apathetic:
>
>    - E.g. *his indifferent attitude toward the suffering of others.*
> 2. having no bias, prejudice, or preference; impartial; disinterested.

Comment: Or in the famous words of Cartman: *"Whateva, I do what I want"*

Comment: Cite the source of your link/block quote definitions in plain text somewhere in the body of your answer

Answer (score 4):

The most neutral term I can think of is **nonconformist**, which can be a noun or an adjective. As a noun, the relevant definition in *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) is

> a person who who does not conform to a generally accepted pattern of thought or action

Answer (score 3):

Virtually all other answers, while certainly apt, connote negatively. *Per* the OP, please allow me to put a positive spin on this personal characteristic.

> [**independently-minded**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/independently-minded) *adjective*: self-reliant and seeking autonomy; see, Collins Dictionary
>
> [**self-reliant**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/self-reliant) *adjective*: Free from the influence, guidance, or control of others; see, the Free Dictionary
>
> [**independent**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/independent) *adjective*: **2**. Free from the influence, guidance, or control of another or others; self-reliant: an *independent* mind. see, the Free Dictionary
>
> [**strong-minded**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/strong-minded) *adjective*:
> **1**. Having a determined will. 2. Having a vigorous, independent mind. see, the Free Dictionary

Answer (score 2):

I'd call someone like that an ***[individualist](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/individualist)***

> http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/individualist
>
> a person who does things without being concerned about what other people will think

Answer (score 2):

Strong-willed

Wiktionary:
adj. Having a vigorous, independent will

Answer (score 1):

I could go with "insubordinate" on this one.

Comment: Welcome to ELU :-). This is a good suggestion, but your answer would be much more useful to the OP and future users of the website if you included a definition and/or examples of usage with adequate references. Thanks!

Comment: ... and citation(s) for your source(s).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a more neutral answer is [**pertinacious.**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pertinacious)

Like obstinacy and stubbornness, it refers to unshakeable opinions. Unlike those other words, pertinacity can be used in either a positive or negative sense.

> 1:  adhering resolutely to an opinion, purpose, or design
>
> perversely persistent
>
> 2:  stubbornly tenacious

Comment: Welcome to ELU :-). This is a great word, but the answer would be even better if you included a reference to a dictionary from which you cited the definition. Thanks!

Comment: ... and citation(s) for your source(s).

Answer (score 1):

Another option: **[bull-headed](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bull-headed)**

> : not willing to change an opinion, plan, etc. : very stubborn in a foolish or annoying way

Answer (score 0):

> oblivious: not aware of or not concerned about what is happening
>   around one.

Ex.: He is oblivious to criticism.

Comment: Cite the source of your block quote definition in plain text somewhere in the body of your answer.

Comment: Source: the dictionary

Answer (score 0):

One with a negative connotation:

> dog·mat·ic  (dôg-măt′ĭk, dŏg-) adj.
>   1. Relating to, characteristic of, or resulting from dogma.
>   2. a. Asserting or insisting upon ideas or principles, especially when unproven or unexamined, in an imperious or arrogant manner: "People in
>   recovery groups can be dogmatic, asserting that the group's way is
>   'the way' or bashing other approaches" (Anne M. Fletcher). b.
>   Characterized by such assertion, often with an unconsidered rejection
>   of criticism: a dogmatic adherence to a single educational model.

Taken from [*here*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dogmatic).

Answer (score 0):

**Selfish**: having or showing concern only for yourself and not for the needs or feelings of other people
[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/selfish)

The selfish person ignores others and does what they want! This certainly covers the 'negative' scenario of OP's question, but also, the bit about "follow[ing] their gut in everything they do".